# No access to docker container's exposed port from host

Tags: postgresql, docker, containers

when I start docker container like this:

```
sudo docker run -p5432:5432 -d -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=test_pass -e POSTGRES_USER=test_user -e POSTGRES_DB=test_db --name postgres postgres:12
```

I can see it's started by command `sudo docker ps`. But when I try to connect to the container from host using

```
psql -Utest_user -p5432 -h localhost -d test_db
```

it just hangs for several minutes and then reports that wasn't able to connect.

But when I add `--net host` option like this:

```
sudo docker run --net host -p5432:5432 -d -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=test_pass -e POSTGRES_USER=test_user -e POSTGRES_DB=test_db --name postgres postgres:12
```

everything starts working as expected, I can connect to the postgresql the same psql command.

The same happens to other containers which I run, not only created from postgres:12 image.

I can only make requests to them when I set `--net host` option.
But I need to expose different ports like for example 2000:5432 to run, for example, several postgres containers simultaneously.
What should I do to make it work? My machine is Ubuntu:20, in case if it matters, and docker is fresh new one installed by instruction from the official site yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

You can't connect to database container because by default it only allows connections from the localhost ( local machines in the same network ).

When you start docker container it makes it's own network ( usually in 172.0.0.0/something ip range).

When you set the flag -net host, docker takes your host's ip address for it's own, and that's why you are able to connect to the database ( because then you are both on the same network ).

The solution is either use the -net host flag, or to edit the config file for the database container to allow external connections which is not recommended.

Comment: Hi, Nikola! Thanks for your answer! But I'm afraid this is not the case, because first of all I managed to connect to postgresql from host by telnet on port 5432, besides this I entered into container by `sudo docker exec postgres bash` and looked into config files and found (`listen_addresses = '*'` in postgresql.conf file) and (`host all all all md5` in pg_hba.conf file).

Comment: In case when you don't use -net host, I think it's necessary  to adjust the hostname, change it from localhost to the name of the container I guess. I am sorry I can't give you more information about it because I don't have much of experience working with postgresql docker container and I don't want to mislead you. But in the case when you don't use -net host, the hostname of the db is not localhost for sure because it's on your network and not on the container's network.

Comment: No worries, I need to check all ideas, so thanks anyway! As for the problem - in the docker run command I map 5432 port from the container to 5432 on the host because I have -p5432:5432 option. So I believe I can use localhost:5432 to connect to the postgresql in the container.